# Java JSONObject won't transform arrays into Json?

Tags: java, json

I'm using this code in Java:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
```

and it will lead to null when I put strings like

```
[{...},{...}, ..., {...}]
```

where `{...}` is a valid JsonObject.

What should I do? I guess json must begin with `{` and end with `}` always. That's because it's null. What should I do? Is there a way to make JSON library deal with this automatically? I can't control the place from where I receive this string of 'json array'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the string you've given isn't an object, but an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html).

You'll have to read it like that (using Java EE's JSON libraries):

```
JsonArray array = jsonReader.readArray();
```

Comment: What should I do in the case where I don't know if I'm gonna receive an array or a json object?

Comment: Parse both and check which value is null?

Comment: Check to see if the first character is a [ or a {